# How do I prod my Droid 2 into resync'ing Facebook profile pictures?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, facebook, motorola-droid-2, motoblur

The Motorola Droid 2 supports, from out-of-the-box, the notion of logging in with not only a Google account, but also a Facebook and Twitter account, and maintains three separate groups of contacts for each of those. It also supports the notion of both manually and automatically linking, say, a Facebook contact to a Google contact. This merges all of the information into a single contact. As this is my first Android phone, I cannot be sure how much of this is basic Android functionality, but I am under the impression a lot of it is from Motorola's MOTOBLUR, and is specific to Motorola handsets.

One problem with it, however, is that a Facebook contact's profile portrait never changes once it's set! When someone changes their Facebook profile portrait, I even get a notification in my timeline that they changed their portrait, with a clickable thumbnail of the new portrait, but their contact image in my phone doesn't ever actually change!

Is there a way to prod MOTOBLUR into resync'ing Facebook profile portraits? I am ***not*** looking for a basic Android application that will try to manually download images and manually match Google names to Facebook names, which would cause more problems than it would solve. I am looking to leverage the functionality already inherent in my MOTOBLUR contacts, and just prod the phone into realizing all of it's images are grossly out of date.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Contacts is actually fairly decoupled from Facebook because Google doesn't like their API and Facebook doesn't want to let their users export data.  I believe this means that if you remove your Facebook account from the phone, those photos will disappear from the contacts.  Then you can re-add the account to get them back.

Unfortunately the contacts are not likely to relink automatically after that, and you'd have to do it manually every time.  I don't know of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I don't have a Motorola phone, and my phone's just doing the standard Android contact linking, but it may also help you. I did this because my previous phone was an HTC Magic running Android 1.6, which had no Contact linking (as that only came with Android 2) so I used one of the apps that downloads the Facebook picture and applies it to the contacts, the picture was then stuck there until I manually got it to update again. Here's what I did to get them updating properly once I moved onto a phone with Froyo:

If you go into your Google Contacts on the web, do you see the old Facebook picture on your contacts there? If so, select the contact. Hover your mouse over their picture until you see the Change Picture link, click that and select No Picture. Save the change.

After a bit the change should sync down to your phone and it should then use the only picture it has - the current Facebook picture.